# Data grid checkbox automation

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

I have a datagrid with a check box. When I click n the cell, I would like the checkbox to be automatically checked when I selected the cell which contains it. what it's doing right now is that I need to select the cell then click on the checkbox and that is quite annoying for us.

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="GridUsureOperation" Margin="10,444,82,6" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource GridMenu}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Opération" Width="*" MinWidth="60" 
                               Binding="{Binding Operation.DescOperation}" 
                               IsReadOnly="True" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Dernière maintenance" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="50"
                               Binding="{Binding DateDerniereMaintenance, StringFormat=yyyy-MM-dd}" 
                               IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Usure dernière maintenance" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="50"
                               Binding="{Binding UsureDerniereOperation}" 
                               IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Fréquence(usure)" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="50"
                               Binding="{Binding QteUsure}" 
                               IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Unité" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="50"
                               Binding="{Binding TypeUsure.Description}" 
                               IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Forcer?" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="50"
                               Binding="{Binding AfficherMaintenance}"                                         
                               IsReadOnly="False">

        </dg:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't like using the DataGridCheckBoxColumn because it needs to have focus before you can interact with the checkbox. So I instead put a CheckBox inside a template column and you only need one click to change state.

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToHeader">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

However, if you actually want the checkbox to change state when they click anywhere in the cell (and not just on the checkbox) you can use the following code, which makes the CheckBox control take up the entire size of the cell.

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToHeader">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="2,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**UPDATE**
I haven't done WPF dev in quite a while. I was having an issue using this solution now that the DataGrid is baked into the WPF libraries and you don't need the toolkit anymore. The checkbox did not want to update the backing property as previously written, so I have added a more complete binding statement that does seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind if they have to click directly on the chcekbox. what I don't want is having to get the focus to be able to click it.